# How to Add empty index.html from each folder and subfolder?

Tags: command-line, webserver

When surfing to any subfolder in my web site the browser displays the list of files in that directory. I would like to add an empty `index.html` file to fix this,

How can I do it with a shell script or a CLI command?

You could disable directory indexes. Via `.htacces`: put this line in the root `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: So basically, if you have `folder/subfolder_a` and `folder/subfolder_b`, you want to have `folder/index.html` , `folder/subfolder_a/index.html` and `folder/subfolder_b/index.html` Correct ?

Comment: @dessert  With `globstar` in bash, yes. With `find`, well . . . depends on number of directories :) But I wanna confirm that's what OP actually wants

Comment: You could disable directory indexes.
Via .htacces: put this line in the root .htaccess

```Options -Indexes```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find top/level/directory -type d -exec touch {}/index.html \;
```

This will find all directories (`-type d`) and for each, execute the command `touch {}/index.html` where {} is replaced by the path name of the directory. `touch` creates a file if it doesn't exist; if it does, `touch` does nothing.

The `\;` at the end signifies the end of the `touch` command.

Just replace `top/level/directory` by the proper path name for your web site.